# Why incorrect calculate cci formula?

Tags: pine-script

```
//CCIn = (TP — SMAnTP) / (0.015 * MDn)
//TP = (High + Low + Close) / 3
//MDn = (|TP1 — SMAnTP1| +…+ | TPn — SMAnTPn |) / n

//@version=4
study(title="Commodity Channel Index", shorttitle="CCI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
length = input(10, minval=1)
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")
ma = sma(src, length)
sum = 0.0
for i = 0 to length - 1
    val = src[i]
    sum := sum + abs(val - ma)
plot(abs(src - ma), "CCI", color=#996A15)
plot(sum, "CCI", color=#996A15)
```

Incorrect calculates sum? I recalculate it in excel and in my own program and don't understand why on TradingView show another result?!

Comment: What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Have you tried the built-in math.sum() function? Otherwise, please explain what's wrong with the results and what is the expected return vs the provided snippet.

Comment: Example: BTCBUSD data (1 hour time frame): array from 13.08.22 16:00 to 14.08.22 01:00 (UTC+3):
length = input(10, minval=1)
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")
ma = sma(src, length)
plot(abs(src - ma), "CCI", color=#996A15):
93.56, 56.18, 3.85, 7.37, 50.65, 5.11, 61.12, 28.05, 25.30, 41.96

sum = 0.0
for i = 0 to length - 1
    val = src[i]
    sum := sum + abs(val - ma)
plot(sum, "CCI", color=#996A15):
Trading View show result: 307.26 - at 14.08.22 01:00, but it should be: 93.56 + 56.18 + 3.85 + 7.37 + 50.65 + 5.11 + 61.12 + 28.05 + 25.30 + 41.96 = 373.15